# Renaming TFS2010 Team Project

Tags: tfs, rename, team-project

Is it possible to rename a TFS2010 team project?

The project in question is based on the CMMI 5.0 team project template, but it has been modified with several custom modifications (new WITs and link types).

For a rename to be feasible, all history must be maintained.

Comment: Check the provided link from Ed Blankenship, now it is possible! :-)

Comment: And now it's been removed with this note from the Author: 'Microsoft has asked me to remove this tool from CodePlex (for now) as the methods used to rename the project can put a project in an unsupportable state (in some scenarios).'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In all: No, it can't be done.

Your only shot is to create a new Team Project named as you 'd like and then move everything to it. This involves serious work done by hand.
After that, you can't erase your old TeamProject - you will loose the history. You can lock it and make it unavailable to everybody.

After having done this a few times we think about the names of our Team Projects *a lot*. If at some point their name is(gets) wrong, I 'd say we 'll live with the mismatch.

Comment: It's as I feared, then. Guess we will have to live with old, uninformed decisions. At any rate, thanks for confirming!

Comment: You can rename Team Projects from TFS 2015: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/04/24/team-project-rename-available-on-vs-online.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, team projects in TFS are not able to be renamed in TFS 2005, TFS 2008, or TFS 2010.  It's currently the #1 feature on the Visual Studio User Voice site for TFS.  If this is something that's important, I'd recommend putting some votes on that feature:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037605-rename-project-in-tfs

Comment: What the ** are "3 votes" - I also gave it 3 votes, but the naming of 1, 2 ,3 votes seems rather strange to me :-)

Comment: +1 +3 and I added a couple of suggestions myself. I didn't even know they were taking suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Check your provided link, now it is possible! :-)

Comment: It is now available in 2015+!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can create a new TeamProject and move your sources while maintaining history. Not sure if work items are preserved even when you delete/destroy the original TeamProject though.

Answer (score 1):

As per the other comments "No, you can't", when we do it here we create a new project and then migrate source and work items over using the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), then delete the original project

Comment: When it copies work items, does it copy the history of those work items, with exact dates and times, so that a side-by-side comparison would show no differences between the two copies of the work-item in the Details:History: section?

Comment: no, all history entries are added in the correct order but IIRC their timestamp is that of the migration and there's some text in front of the comment saying something like "Workitem updated by XXX for YYY "